# Increased RAM when using browserify with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, browserify, ram

I have a NodeJS application which i bundle with Browserify due to decrease the startup time of this app. Additional the app is uglified.

The startup time is decreased and the app works as it should work. But compared with the unbundled version of the app it consumes an extra of ca. 6-9 MB RAM.

Can anyone explain this extra of RAM? My only idea is that the Garbage Collector can not work as efficient with the bundled app as with the unbundled one.

Comment: Do you do any transpiling (e.g. with Babel) or add any polyfills?

Comment: Are you enabling [source map](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) files? Loading the map files in memory for aiding with runtime debugging would probably consume around that much memory, if not more, depending on the size of the original script.

Comment: @str: i dont use Babel and don't add anything.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Sourcemaps are disabled

Comment: If you're not using babel or source maps, you might as well just concatenate your files together and run uglify, you don't need browserify to do that. As it is, this question is impossible to answer without guessing, so I'm voting to close as off-topic until you provide sufficient information about your project's configuration. See [help] and [mcve], then [edit] your question.

Comment: I use sourcemaps. But not to test the RAM consumption.